# Magento 2.3: Unable to see the My account page for the customer who logged in via google

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account, login, social

I have installed **Amasty Social Login extension** on our **Magento 2 site**. After installing the extension, I have logged in to the site using Google login. **However, In the frontend, it shows like I didn't log in and can't able to see the My account page**. But in the admin panel, I can see the customer details who logged in via google or other type social logins.

In order to make this work, what I have to do?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Please try Simply social login https://bit.ly/3b5U5Tc

Comment: ok you can't see here as well who logged in by google account

Answer (score -1):

As this is paid extension you can probably create a ticket in Amasty Support section.